# Multi Tenancy with Multiple Users Multi Multi Tenancy

Tags: django, dns, multi-tenant

Hello I am working on an a project where multi-tenancy is needed.
In my case tenant is a company and with in that company you ll have multiple users.

Lets say our company is called abc and our domain is domain.com.
So abc.domain.com reaches the abc's resources.

Now should each request check to see if subdomain is valid at application server level given that our dns is registered as *.domain.com (for simplicity lets forget about www as a domain)

or should you explicitly register each subdomain (In this case is the registration of subdomains instant) IS this a common practice to actually write a script that adds the each subdomain explicitly. Starting a new tenant would take a lot longer I think.

but if a wildchar is used you would need to make sure that that domain exists, so maybe a DB request is necessary or
alternatively maybe you can attach the domain to your token or jwt or whatnot.

How do one go about handling the domains ?

Comment: Isn't a db request needed anyway to get the content for the domain?

Comment: Not really because if you have a tenant t1 and when request comes to t1.app.com you extract the t1 from url and route the request to db  and in this case we skip the tenant look/check up and just route the data. I guess what I am asking is should one make sure the domain exists before trying to do database op,  should the domain check be done at dns level and not app level by the way which is impossible if you have "*" as subdomain in dns settings or adding tenant explicitly to dns server punish others as there is down time or up time to get the dns going

Comment: If the request to the db comes back as failed because the tenant doesn't exist, you throw a 404 error.